# Is there a way to do lookups on default record values?

Tags: erlang, records

Given a record

```
-record(something, {id                :: integer(),
                    name              :: string(),
                    email = undefined :: string() | undefined}).
```

Is there a way to get the default values for the fields, in this example getting the fact that `#something.email` defaults to undefined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Records are syntactic sugar in Erlang**, expanded by the compiler. The following solution, suggested by @Dmitry, works, but the compiler will not optimize it away unless you pass +inline, since the trick here is to really create a record:

```
g() -> (#something{})#something.email.
```

Such record syntactic sugar will be expanded to: (use `erlc -E`)

```
g() ->
    case {something,undefined,undefined,undefined} of
        {something,_,_,rec0} ->
            rec0;
        _ ->
            error({badrecord,something})
    end.
```

and this will eventually become: (use `erlc -S`)

```
{function, g, 0, 4}.
  {label,3}.
    {line,[{location,"test.erl",10}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,test},{atom,g},0}.
  {label,4}.
    {move,{literal,{something,undefined,undefined,undefined}},{x,0}}.
    {test,is_tuple,{f,5},[{x,0}]}.
    {test,test_arity,{f,5},[{x,0},4]}.
    {get_tuple_element,{x,0},0,{x,1}}.
    {get_tuple_element,{x,0},3,{x,2}}.
    {test,is_eq_exact,{f,5},[{x,1},{atom,something}]}.
    {move,{x,2},{x,0}}.
    return.
  {label,5}.
    if_end.
```

The `#something.email` part of the expression not only means getting the email field of the created record, but also checking that the passed record is well formed. This test is currently not optimized by default. Fortunately, you can optimize it with `-compile([inline]).` in your module or `+inline` on the command line.

The following solution is simpler for the compiler:

```
f() -> element(#something.email, #something{}).
```

Record syntactic sugar (here #something.email is the index of email field) will expand to:

```
f() ->
    element(4, {something,undefined,undefined,undefined}).
```

In this case, we do not tell Erlang to test anything about `#something{}` being a proper #something record. The compiler always optimizes calls to `element/2` built-in function. So this will eventually become:

```
{function, f, 0, 2}.
  {label,1}.
    {line,[{location,"test.erl",7}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,test},{atom,f},0}.
  {label,2}.
    {move,{atom,undefined},{x,0}}.
    return.
```

Please note that the default value for any field **is `undefined` unless explicitly provided**. As a result, your code:

```
-record(something, {id                :: integer(),
                    name              :: string(),
                    email = undefined :: string() | undefined}).
```

is equivalent to:

```
-record(something, {id    = undefined :: integer() | undefined,
                    name  = undefined :: string()  | undefined,
                    email = undefined :: string()  | undefined}).
```

Yet, your code seems to mean that id always be an `integer()` and never `undefined`, and likewise that name always be a `string()`. This is untrue. If this is what you mean, you should provide a default value different from `undefined`:

```
-record(something, {id    = 0   :: integer(),
                    name  = ""  :: string(),
                    email       :: string()}).
```

Only providing a default value will tell [dialyzer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) that id and name can never be `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

Construct empty record and look at some field: `(#something{})#something.email`.