# Get default value from Erlang record definition?

Tags: erlang, record, default-value

Is there an easy way to get a default value from an Erlang record definition? Suppose I have something like this:

```
-record(specialfield, {
    raw = <<"default">> :: string()
}).
```

I would like to have some way to retrieve the default value of the `raw` field. Something like this would be very simple:

```
 #specialfield.raw % => <<"default">>
```

This is not possible. I would need to instantiate a record in order to get the default value:

```
 Afield = #specialfield{}
 DefaultValue = Afeild#specialfield.raw
 DefaultValue % => <<"default">>
```

Is there an easier way of doing this? I seems like there should be some way to retrieve the default value without having to create an instance of the record.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to do lookups on default record values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116330/is-there-a-way-to-do-lookups-on-default-record-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing an empty record and accessing one field can be done on one line:

```
(#specialfield{})#specialfield.raw.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
raw_default() -> <<"default">>.

-record(specialfield, { raw = raw_default() }).
```

And now you have a function with the default in it. This will be extremely fast since it is a function call to a constant value. If this is also too slow, enable inlining.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [erlang - records](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html#id83618), search section "11.8".

There's not much special about records - they're just a tuple at runtime.  So to get the field `raw` from the tuple of default values that is the internal representation of #specialfield{} you would use:

```
element(#specialfield.raw, #specialfield{}).
```

In this case, `#specialfield.raw` is the index of the value for `raw` in the #specialfield tuple.  When you pass in `specialfield` that resolves to a tuple in the form `{specialfield, <<"default">>}`.